# SQL XML parsing split the string on letters 'TH'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split a string into multiple values based on a special symbol. e.g., Here is the string

> JdwnrhþTHIMPHUþOTHþþ10/1991þ02/02/2011þBHUTAN

I want it to be:

> Jdwnrh THIMPHU OTH  10/1991 02/02/2011 BHUTAN

I am using the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50)
SET @delimiter='þ' 
;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(DATA as nvarchar(MAX)), @delimiter , '</M><M>'), '&', '&amp;') + '</M>' AS XML) 
        AS BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML
    FROM [JACS_RAVEN_DATA_OLD].dbo.BDWCREGPREVADDR
)

SELECT
     BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML.value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As streetNo,
     BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML.value('/M[2]', 'varchar(50)') As suburb,
     BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML.value('/M[3]', 'varchar(3)') As stateCode,
     BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML.value('/M[4]', 'varchar(10)') As postalCode,
     BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML.value('/M[7]', 'varchar(50)') As country,
     BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML.value('/M[5]', 'varchar(50)') As dateFrom,
     BDWCREGPREVADDR_XML.value('/M[6]', 'varchar(50)') As dateTo
FROM CTE
GO
```

The query works well on all the strings other than the one provided as an example. For above the string, the query returns the following:

> 'Jdwnrh' ' ' 'IMPHU' 'O' ' ' '10/1991' '02/02/2011' 'BHUTAN'

It seems the code takes letters 'TH' as a new attribute and split the string on it. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This looks like SQL Server so I added the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Does this happen if you use `nvarchar()` for all the strings?

Comment: The `þ` is likely being considered [equivalent to "th"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_\(letter\))

Comment: Yes, even with all nvarchar() I get the same output.

Comment: Blorgbeard, I agree. But how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you change the collation of the source column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to your collation. In `Latin1_General_CS_AS`, the `þ` character is considered equivalent to `th` (because it's an [Old English letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)) that sounds like "th" when pronounced).

```
print replace('thornþ' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS,'þ','1') 
' output: 1orn1
```

This is not the case for all collations; for example, in `Latin1_General_BIN` they are separate:

```
print replace('thornþ' collate Latin1_General_BIN,'þ','1') 
' output: thorn1
```

So perhaps you could look at [changing the collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx) of the column which contains the þ characters.

Comment: Thanks. I used the following query to change the collation of my source table and it works now. ALTER TABLE [JACS_RAVEN_DATA_OLD].dbo.BDWCREGPREVADDR ALTER COLUMN DATA text COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;

Answer (score 0):

the key(þ) is wrong ,if you change another word ,it's ok. when use key(þ) and key(z), there are two results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbAgm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNyUd.png)
I think maybe the key(þ) has some special meaning. hope to help you